# iOS 15 develop CaptureOutput never called, using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here is my code:

```swift
import AVFoundation

/// CMSampleBuffer
@objcMembers
final class CameraOutput: TOutput, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    private var videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    
    private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession =  AVCaptureSession()
    
    override func start() {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) {
            granted in
            if granted {
                self.runCamera()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func runCamera() {
        self.videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        do {
            captureSession.beginConfiguration()
            let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)!)
            captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
            captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
                NSLog("Camera on!")
            }
            NSLog("Camera on!")
        } catch (_){}
    }
    
    
    public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
//        let image: UIImage? = ImageConverter.convert(from: sampleBuffer)
        NSLog("Capture get")
//        callAllListeners(image)
    }
}
```

After I run the start, It showed a permission　alert and allowed it.
And The Camera using the badge changes to green, but after one second it goes out.
CaptureOutput(...){...} never called.......

- my class `TOutput` is extended `NSObject`.
- "Camera on!" was logged twice.
- XCode version: Version 14.0.1 (14A400)
- OS version: 12.6（21G115）
- iOS version: 15.0.1
- Machine type: M1 chip

I searched on the net but could not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, I was creating a `CameraOutput` in a method, so after the method, the object was removed by GC.